# Is there any simplest way to allow the user with the specific condition to see a page?

Tags: symfony

Currently, There is a checkout page with the security as below.

```
/**
 * @Route("/checkout")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
 */
```

Now all admins are able to view this page, I want to allow the user with specific conditions to visit this page along with all admins.

I can do this by removing security and adding a condition in the each action.

So is there any Symfony way to handle this easily?

Comment: can you put your security.yml file

Comment: the easiest way would be a symfony firewall

Comment: If you want custom conditions for your page you have to write in each action.

Comment: I think you're looking for Voters https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Answer (score 0):

You have many possibilities:

1. @Security and do something like:

   ```
   /**
    * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="admin_post_edit")
    * @Security("user.getEmail() == post.getAuthorEmail()")
   */
   public function editAction(Post $post)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```

Note, you always have access to user, and you also have access to the `post` entity, because you have `Post $post`. Sometime, you can need the @ParamConverter to.

2. Just do a condition and if true: `throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('You cannot access this page!');`
3. For more complex controls, you can use a voter (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html)
4. For very complex controls: ACL (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own custom function that will grant access or not, and then call it from the annotation. That function could be something like

`return hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') || anotherCondition();`

See more here
https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html#security-voters